In prisma orderBy _count cant take where clause
Problem
Currently, if I try to sort users based on number of posts they have below is the query to be executed.
const getUsers = await prisma.user.findMany({ take: 10, orderBy: { posts: { _count: 'desc', }, }, })
But, if I want to sort users based on number of posts who have a postname as 'AdamCopeland', I seemingly cannot.
It would be better to have something like this ->
const getUsers = await prisma.user.findMany({
  take: 10,
  orderBy: {
    posts: {
      _count: {
          where:{
              name : "AdamCopeland"
           },
           value:"desc"     //order of sort
       },
    },
  },
})

